# Prolog CLPFD Transitivity

Tags: prolog, clpfd

"Obvious" is not a word lightly bandied about, but why does SWI-Prolog's CLPFD correctly solve this:

```
?- A+1 #= A*2.
A = 1.
```

but not this:

```
?- B #= A + 1, B #= A * 2.
A+1#=B,
A*2#=B.
```

(`label` and `indomain` yield `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.)

Is it just...the solver doesn't catch that case?  (I'd sure have expected it to apply transitivity.)  Or is it a symptom of some deeper syntactic conundrum, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tries to solve the constraint from the values in the domain of each variable! As the domain of `B` and `A` is infinite and not bound, backtracking over a constraint satisfaction will be delayed and the program is stopped.

It means it tries to find some solution for the constraint `B #= A + 1`, but it finds many (infinite values for `A` and `B`) and also the same for the second constraint. Hence it will be stopped here as the possible values of `A` and `B` are infinite. However, the result is not `No`. It is `Yes` with 2 delayed goals.

```
B = B{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}
A = A{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}
There are 2 delayed goals.
```

To solve this, you need to bound at least one of the `A` or `B`. For example, if you run this query `A::1..1000, B#=A+1,  B #= A*2.`, you will get the same result as for the first query in your examples. And also, there is not any deduction in `clpfd` to resolve the transitivity as it uses from the backtracking method.

In sum, it is one of the shortcomings of the library that you are using, as it will be stopped when the domain of a constraint with more than one variable has an infinite domain and you can solve it by setting a bounded domain for at least one of the variables.

Comment: If that's the case, though, why can it solve `A+1 #= A*2`?  `A`'s domain is still infinite.

Comment: @Erhannis Because there is just one free variable! but in `B #= A+1` there are infinite answers besides infinite domain!

Comment: Hmm.  `B` isn't actually free, though.  If you know `A`, you know `B`, and vice versa.  I don't think it makes a logical difference.  However, considering that the solver _does_ solve one and not the other, I guess I'll mark your answer correct.  If anybody can provide a more satisfying explanation, though, I'm all ears.